# Reaction of conjugated alkene with KNH2

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, elimination

I could not think of this reaction fitting into any of the reactions I know except the aryne mechanism. And hence I came up with the following mechanism after seeing the answer (which I've written in the picture next to question). Please tell if my proposed mechanism is correct.

Also, I am highly unsure of the fact that the last species formed will be able to extract a hydrogen atom from somewhere in the solution.

**Question:**

[image]

This is my **proposed mechanism**:

[image]

---

**Source:** Joint Entrance Exam (JEE) 1997 India

Comment: If the product is indeed correct (diphenylacetylene), I would suggest alpha-elimination to form a carbene which rearranges with phenyl shift to give the alkyne product

Comment: I have never seen any alkene form a carbene before. Could you please give an example of a reaction where you have seen such a thing. Or tell, why would it happen.. Please..

Comment: @orthocresol I believe you are correct. Deprotonation of the bromo-alkene to give the C(K)Br species will certainly give rise to a carbene (or metallocarbene) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbene   and the phenyl shift seems the obvious route to the product

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a flowchart of what the commenters have stated. An α-elimination occurs stepwise **1** --> **2** --> **3**. There is a phenyl migration (bridged?) to afford tolane **4**. [Look here for this chemistry](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01302a066?journalCode=jacsat&quickLinkVolume=58&quickLinkPage=2310&selectedTab=citation&volume=58).

[image]

Comment: Try this: J. Am. Chem. Soc., (1936), 58, 2310. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01302a066?journalCode=jacsat&quickLinkVolume=58&quickLinkPage=2310&selectedTab=citation&volume=58

Comment: Can this mechanism be concerted? That is, the abstraction of proton, migration of phenyl and elimination of Br all in a single step?

Comment: Is the reaction concerted? Perhaps. I haven't researched it. I suspect that the deprotonation may be reversible. There are alkylidene carbenes that undergo intramolecular C-H insertion. http://www1.udel.edu/chem/valhalla/alkylidene.html

Comment: I have a doubt in the migration step. I would have thought that the bottom phenyl migrates, not the top one - similar to how in Beckmann rearrangement, the group trans to the leaving $\ce{-OH2^+}$ migrates - isn't this reaction similar with $\ce{-OH2^+}$ replaced by $\ce{-Br}$, and a carbon in place of the nitrogen?